# CASE WHEN PostgreSQL only working for one case

Tags: sql, postgresql, switch-statement, case

I'm writing a query that will go into some golang backend code to autopopulate some billing fields that we have. Basically there's a standard fee and a reduced fee. There's a table of these fees, the ID number, and the effective date.

If the ID number is in the list, I want to just select the fee for that ID number. 
If the ID number is not in the list, I want to select the standard fee.

On the statements we get, we are given the MemberID. The MemberID joins with a CorporateID (CorpID) in a CorporateLinks table. If the MemberID is *not* in the CorporateLinks table at all, I want to select the standard fee.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN cl.CorpID IN (SELECT CorpID FROM ConversionFactor) THEN MAX(cf.ConversionFactor)
WHEN MemberID NOT IN (SELECT MemberID FROM CorporateLinks) THEN MAX(cf.ConversionFactor)
ELSE MAX(cf.ConversionFactor) 
END 
FROM ConversionFactor cf
LEFT JOIN CorporateLinks cl
ON cf.CorpID = cl.CorpID
WHERE EffectiveDate = (SELECT EffectiveDate FROM ConversionFactor
                       WHERE EffectiveDate < $2
                       ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC LIMIT 1)
AND MemberID = $1
GROUP BY cl.CorpID, cl.MemberID;
```

When the MemberID maps to a CorpID and the CorpID is in the list, it returns it perfectly.
When the MemberID is NOT in CorporateLinks, it returns an empty field. 
I haven't found a test case where the MemberID is in CorporateLinks but CorpID is not in ConversionFactor (`ELSE` Case).

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm not very well versed in using CASE WHEN statements in queries, I've only used them in functions before to perform regex operations.

Comment: Is ConversionFactor a table or a column? You seem to be using it in both contexts.

Comment: It's both -- I've updated it to say cf.ConversionFactor where it is a column, it's the main column of interest in the ConversionFactor table.

Comment: Best practice is to qualify *ALL* column references. Given the join condition for `cf` and `cl`, requiring the values of `corpid` to match, I'm failing to see any possible value for `cl.corpid` that won't be returned by the subquery, i.e. the first WHEN in the CASE is always going to be satisfied.  I'm also suspicious of the GROUP BY

Comment: There are many cases in my real data where there is not a corpID in the table, or the memberID we get does not map to a corpID. This is why I need like a default value, hence the MAX since there are two options for fees, and I want the higher one. The effective date will always be satisfied, and there will always be a memberID, but the memberID may not exist in the CorpID table at all, or the memberID might map to a CorpID that does not exist in the ConversionFactor table. I can see I made a mistake on the join but with LEFT JOIN it's no different.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would go a long ways to clarifying the specification. There are parts of the query that need to be fixed before addressing the CASE expression. Since `MemberID` is a column in `CorporateLinks` table (we know that from a subquery in the CASE expression, and the query isn't throwing an ambiguous column error), the condition in the WHERE clause requiring a non-NULL value, that negates the outerness of the left join rendering it equivalent to an inner join. (Maybe we mean for the outer join to be the otherway around?)

Answer (score 1):

There are several questionable things about your query.

The parts relevant to the discussion look like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... IN (SELECT ...)
            THEN conversionfactor
            WHEN ... NOT IN (SELECT ...)
            THEN max(conversionfactor)
            ELSE max(conversionfactor)
       END
FROM ...
GROUP BY ..., conversionfactor, ...;
```

Observations:

1. There can be only a single value of `conversionfactor` in each group, because that column is part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

   So it makes no sense to write `max(conversionfactor)` - it is going to be the same as `conversionfactor`.
2. The second `THEN` branch and the `ELSE` branch both return `max(conversionfactor)`, so the second `WHEN` clause is superfluous.

Since all three branches return the same value, the whole `CASE` expression can be replaced with `conversionfactor`, because that is always going to be the result.

But your actual question is why the `CASE` expression returns an "empty field".

From the above discussion that would mean that `conversionfactor` is either an empty string (if it is a string type) or NULL.

Now there is no reason why this shouldn't be the case. You have to examine your data and look for NULL values or empty strings in that column. The `CASE` expression is useless, but it is not at fault for that.

Comment: You are mistaken. The OP is missing results because they are (perhaps unwittingly) using an INNER JOIN when the foreign key could be NULL.

Comment: Regarding point 1, if there are multiple ConversionFactor values, multiple rows will be returned, not just one due to the GROUP BY. This is probably not what is intended.

Comment: Yes, per grouped ConversionFactor. If there are two different values for it, it will be split into two different rows. GROUP BY only merges when the values are the same. Performing an aggregate function on a column listed within GROUP BY is probably not going to return what the OP expects.

Comment: It might not return what I expect, however I get an error if I take it out of the group by clause (which is why I put it in in the first place). I did mistakenly have an inner join instead of a left join. However I'm still running into issues. The query by itself -- ie when I do `SELECT MAX(ConversionFactor) FROM ... WHERE EffectiveDate...AND MemberID NOT IN (SELECT)` returns the value I want. If I need to write a different query that's fine, I only posted here because I got stuck. However I'd rather have one query to integrate into go than 3 different queries and do backend logic to pick

Comment: As well: there are no empty strings or null values in the conversion factor data. I just confirmed this.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, you are right about that. As I mentioned in my answer `max(conversionfactor)` will be the same as `conversionfactor`.

Comment: @datadumn you get the error because the column appears without `max` in one of the branches of the `CASE` statement. Columns that do not appear in (or are not implied by) the `GROUP BY` clause can only be used in aggregate functions.

Comment: Ok - I changed that to MAX() too and took it out of the groupby. It still only works for the first case.

Comment: If you replace the whole `CASE` expression with `max(conversionfactor)` as I suggested, the result will be the same, right?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a `LEFT JOIN`. The default join type if you don't specify is an `INNER JOIN`, and so if there is no entry in `ConversionFactor` that matches, the result set will omit it completely, not just set the relevant column(s) to `NULL`. Also your `WHERE` clause explicitly filters for `MemberId`. If `MemberId` is `NULL`, you'll never see any results as a result either.

You are also using sub-selects when it's not clear you need them. Once you switch to the `LEFT JOIN` see what the output looks like with a simple selection:

```sql
SELECT cf.*, cl.*
FROM ConversionFactor cf
  LEFT JOIN CorporateLinks cl USING (CorpID)
WHERE cf.EffectiveDate < $2
LIMIT 100 -- Limit for a sanity check to prevent too many results as you debug
```

Once you can see your whole result set, it should be easier to work out how you want to filter and aggregate later by editing which columns you want returned.

It's quite possible that you don't need the `CASE` statement at all.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the column `conversionfactor` and the table `conversionfactor`. Besides, I don't see how an outer join would make any difference. OP complains about unexpected NULLs, and if anything there would be more of them with an outer join.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Who brought up an outer join? I spoke of an inner join converted to a left join.

Comment: "Left join" is short for "left outer join".

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. I was thinking you meant full outer join. However my comment still stands. An inner join with what is written will omit results when the foreign key column is NULL. That's why the case statement fails under some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, an inner join might have fewer result rows. But that does not turn values to NULL. A group with no members simply does not appear in the output, but you seem to think that it will, and that the aggregate function will return NULL. This is, however, not the case.

Comment: it's not null. I'm not getting back [null], I am getting back nothing.

Comment: @datadumn Right, which was the point I was trying to make. When you perform an INNER JOIN on another table where the foreign key column does not reference anything in the joined table, the row is completely omitted. No result. There's nothing to run `max()` on since there are no results that map to both joined tables. Perhaps I was unclear, but I never said you would get a NULL. I said the result was omitted. If you run my first query, what do you get back?